# Ubuntu 16.04 (I think?): I'm very new to Ubuntu and Unity has disappeared

Tags: unity

Unity has disappeared and every single solution I find ends in errors including or similar to

> E: Sub-process usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I can't install anything, and unless I'm doing something wrong it seems like I can't even reinstall Ubuntu. I have no idea how to fix the problem now, as I said, every solution I find comes in error.

Comment: We need to know for sure what version of Ubuntu you're using. Can you press Cntrl+Alt+F1, log in, and tell us what typing `lsb_release -a` gives you? (The line that says 'Description')

Comment: Edit the question and give full error message

Answer (score 0):

If you can login and you got a empty desktop try right click on the wallpaper, open a terminal or hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Then restart unity:

```
unity --replace
```

If the unity package is broken more information will be show in the terminal. If not then the desktop should load.

Ultimatley you can reinstall the whole unity desktop:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Also you can install other desktop until you fix the unity:

```
sudo apt install gnome
```

Comment: I'm getting "Bus error (core dumped).

Comment: Uh, that error is kind of bad, it can be fixed but it may take hours/days of looking log files. I suggest you to reinstall the whole system if gnome does not working.

Comment: I tried but it just won't let me reinstall it.

Comment: @NautilusPsy If the live installer cannot load then your hardware is not compatible with ubuntu or your installer is broken.